# Person AccountId

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We do work with SF PersonAccounts. When creating the user in our MasterDE we use the PersonContactId (0017...) as SubscriberKey. After a while Salesforce creates a new contact with AccountId (0037) at all contacts. Does the PersonAccount now counts two times against contact count? If so, is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Hi Michael I try to understand the way you have set this up. After a new subscriber is added to the data extension, a new person account is created in SF I hope? Or is a new contact created?

Comment: Hi Fred, We're doing it from API side. We first create the person Account, fetch the PersonContactId and then create the MasterDE entry with PersonContactId.

Answer (score 0):

A convenient way to sync data and to prevent duplicates in this scenario is to make use of a synchronized data source. You have to make use of the Marketing Cloud Connector for this to work. Changes in Salesforce are automatically synced to the DE based on the poll schedule settings.